# Where does Plink command look out for the private keys?

Tags: ssh, putty, plink

I am trying to connect a Linux machine from Windows using passwordless SSH connection. I generated the keys using PuTTYgen in the Windows machine and copied the keys to the Linux machine appropriately.

From the command prompt of windows I could access passwordless using the below command:

```
ssh user@ipaddress
```

When I use Plink, if I issue the below command the passwordless connection is going through:

```
plink user@ipaddress -i <path to private ppk>
```

My question here is: in case I use `plink -batch` option, where does the private key file will be picked from if I don't mention `-i` option?

In other words, which is the default location of ppk file which Plink is looking for?

For example:

```
plink -batch user@ipaddress
```

Answer (score 1):

Plink does not have any default location for private keys.

What you should do instead, is load the private key into [Pageant](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter9.html#pageant) (PuTTY authentication agent).